# Eclipse warning: unchecked conversion vs redundant specification of type arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-warnings

I just recently switched from JDK1.6 to JDK 1.7.

I have this code:

```
SomeClass<SomeType> someVariable = new SomeClass<SomeType>(createSomeObject());
```

Now I'm getting a warning:

```
Redundant specification of type arguments <SomeType>
```

If I use the quick fix Eclipse gives me this:

```
SomeClass<SomeType> someVariable = new SomeClass<>(createSomeObject());
```

Which results in

```
Got an exception - expecting EOF, found 'xyz'
```

xyz is the next item in my code text.

When I remove the angled brackets, I get this warning:

```
SomeClass is a raw type. References to generic type SomeClass<M> should be parameterized
```

If I add the type parameter I end up with the first warning (redundant spec...)

WTF is going on?

I want to keep both warnings and I'm still using Eclipse 3.7.1. I'm not willing to update my Eclipse, if there's another way to solve this problem, since it'll take me some time to configure it the way I want it again.

Comment: Check your Eclipse Java "compile to version" setting. That might still be set to 1.6, rather than 7

Comment: @MrSpoon Do you mean "Compiler compliance level" under Preferences-Compiler-JDK Compliance? That's set to 1.7.

Comment: Yeah, that one. That's a shame. That "Got an exception" error doesn't look like a standard compiler error to me. So, I guess its coming from another Eclipse builder. What other builders do you have enabled in "Project/Properties/Builders"?

Comment: Java Builder and Checkstyle Builder

Comment: Ahhh, disable Checkstyle. Quick google search reckons that "Got an exception" is related to Checkstyle. Maybe Checkstyle doesn't support 1.7 yet, or you need to update just that plugin.

Comment: Yes, it was checkstyle. I could figure out by clicking on the "configure annotations" button of the error dialog in eclipse. Updating the checkstyle plugin made the error disappear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Redundant specification of type arguments `<SomeType>`

comes from Java 7's [type inference mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). Specifying the generic types twice is indeed redundant, since the compiler can intuit what you require simply from

```
SomeClass<SomeType> someVariable = new SomeClass<>(createSomeObject());
```

and consequently you don't need the generic type in both the declaration and definition (type inference *could* go further - e.g. with Scala you simply declare the LHS as a `val` or `var`, and the compiler knows what type it really needs to be).

Comment: Perfect, but is there a way to tell MapStruct to generate proper Java 8 code?